# I made a program that randomly generates 0s and 1s in a loop. How do I make it so that the loop stops when the program generates ten 0s in a row?

Tags: java, string, math, loops, random

Here is the cod I have so far:

```
public class Laboratoire05E {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number = 0;
    int counter = 0;

     do {
        bin = (int) (Math.random()*2);
        System.out.print(bin);
        counter++;

        if(counter>=80) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            counter = counter-80;
            }
        } while (bin < 2);
}
```

}

And the output at the console is as follows:

01000111000011101011010011011000000100100110100101011011010100111011111110110111
00101100001001100010001100101001101110011000110110111010100010011111000101110011
00000010111101011110100100100100000101001111000110001101010011000001110100000011
10100001001011100110100110010011100110001110100111111110111101111000010100001110
11011001110001101111110111010111111110100110100000100001011100011100011001000101
01001111111011001101000010111010111010111100001101010001100001101011111010001111
00110010110101100010000101001111011111

and this goes on indefinitely.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What approach do you think would work?

Answer (score 7):

Bear in mind that your loop may will find 10 '0's in a row `(.5^10) = 0.0977 %` of the time. If you increase that amount you may want to put an additional check for when `counter` exceeds some threshold for number of numbers generated.

```
int zeroCount = 0
do {
    bin = (int) (Math.random()*2);
    System.out.print(bin);
    counter++;

    // Check for 10 in row:
    if(bin == 0) {
        zeroCount ++;
    } else {
        zeroCount = 0;
    }
    if(zeroCount == 10) {
        break;  // Exit loop
    }

    if(counter>=80) {
        System.out.print("\n");
        counter = counter-80;
        }
} while (bin < 2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful. Also I figured the 10 0s in a row would take long, I just used 10 as an example. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually it won't take that long to find 10 0's - about 2^10 or 1,024 tries.

Comment: @DStanley Actually my math is correct; if you solve `x*0.000977 = 1` you get `1024` tries. I just was overestimating that to be a "long" loop.

Comment: @NominSim - I wasn't refuting your math, but it's not a "long time". 1,000 simple loops would run in a matter of milliseconds.

Answer (score 5):

Creating a `Random` can be slightly more efficient

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    int bin = rand.nextInt(2);
    System.out.print(bin);
    if (bin == 1) i = 0;
}
```

prints for example:

> 111101001011001001011000111100010110011001011111011100001110100011100100100101101011110110111101101010110111000000110111011010111001101111010100111011000000101011000100000010001001010010011100100011111100010100011101101111100100111110110101101010111010001111111010000101010011100110111100010001100011011011101001000010001001010010110000011000001011101001110001111110000101101100011100111110000010000010001100000001011110110000110000001000100010001010000111001111111111100101101111110101011000010101110000110010011111001100100010111001001010110100001111011001000101011101101010110110010010001000001011010101000001000101011001000101000001111100111011110111101100010010110100001111011111110000011001010111100101100100110101101101000011100101011010111001110011110011110010001110001111001101000001111001001100101101010111101000000101011011110100001001100000111100000101111010111011000010110011001010011000001001101001100011101100001000100110101011000100010010001011100100100010000111111010001010000001101011010101101001000110110011110000100101100100000000101001100011110110000000000

Comment: Its what I got. ;) tens zeros will typically take 2^^10 or 1024 digits.

Comment: @ahenderson You are right that the output is likely to be the most expensive part. Whether buffer is needed isn't clear.

Comment: Just to nitpick, the mathematical expectation is 1024 + 10 = 1034 digits :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't think that is right, `1/(0.5^10)` = 1024 digits

Comment: @NominSim At the very start, before any digits are generated, there is a 1/1024 chance that the next 10 digits will all be zero. Do the induction from that onwards.

Comment: I think that is reflected in the `1/(0.5^10)=1024` equation is it not?

Comment: @NominSim What exactly do you reckon that equation is about? 0.5^10 is the probability for any randomly chosen streak of digits to be all zeros. 1/that is the mathematical expectation for the number of draws you need to make to get, on average, exactly one "hit". If you consider all possible streaks, the first 1024 of them cover the first 1034 digits. These are not independent choices, however, so I'm still worried if the calculation is sound.

Comment: There is a 1/1024 chance, the *next* 10 digits will be zero, so I agree the expected length is 1024 + 10.

Answer (score 2):

1. initialize a counter variable to zero outside the loop
2. if the random result is 0, increment the counter, else reset the counter to 0
3. if the counter == 10, break

Answer (score 2):

A bitwise solution is fun...

```
int mask = 0x3FF; // masks last 10 bits
int buffer = mask; // initialize buffer to all ones

while ((mask & buffer) != 0) {
    int digit = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    buffer = (buffer << 1) | digit;
}
```